# git fetch changes german umlauts

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, git-fetch

I have multiple git repositories that are all utf-8 encoded and display umlauts correctly. I want them to be combined into a single repo (each original repo is a single branch in the new one). My system is configured to use utf-8 as the default git encoding.
I do the following steps:

```
git init test (initializes as utf-8)
cd test
git remote add test_remote C:/temp/remote_repo
git fetch --all
git checkout -b test_local test_remote/master
```

After that, i have the remote branch master in the local branch test_local with all commits. My problem is, that the german umlauts aren't shown correctly, but git log gives something like Ã¼ for ü.

My question is, why does git fetch change encodings and why isn't it shown correctly in the new repo, as it is also utf-8?

I attached an example of how i fetch the remote repo and the commit message changes while the commit hash stays the same: 
[Git Bash Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTfEL.png)

Comment: Git generally *doesn't* touch any of your data at all: it's all just raw byte strings. Any encoding interpretation is up to other software, such as the editor looking at extracted files, or the pager looking at commits. There are some nasty corner cases, though, with some OSes insisting on messing with path names. It's thus important to specify your OS and precisely where the characters appear: in commit metadata such as log messages, file metadata such as file names, or file data stored in the repository.

Comment: I use windows 10 and work without an editor but just the git command line. The false encoding only appears in the commit message, all other data and metadata are fine as far as i can see. If I use git show in the original repo, it displays the umlauts correctly, if i use the same command in the fetched repo, there are cryptic signs in it.

Comment: I don't use Windows so I can't really help, but it's certainly some setting that Windows somehow is not understanding. The raw data in the commit message literally *cannot* be altered, ever: that would change the commit hash, so that it's no longer the same commit. Someone more familiar with Windows 10 can probably pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first i tried to change the codepage of my windows command line by executing `chcp 65001`. As that didn't work, i tried to set the os language for programs that do not support unicode to utf-8 but that didn't work either.

After a long search, i discovered that the problem was in the source repository, where `git config --list` showed, that `i18n.commitencoding` is set to some windows encoding. After switching it to utf-8, everything works perfect now.

Comment: How to switch it though?